# Mixing Mocks and Beans using Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I'm writing unit tests using Mockito/JUnit with a Java Spring application.  I have a Service class which has some injected dependencies (injected using @Autowired field dependency, although that can be changed).  Some of these are other dependencies in the project (e.g. data access object), others are various utility classes from libraries (e.g. Jackson ObjectMapper).  Due to the principle of "do not test other people's code", I would like to mock the former class of dependencies but not the latter.  How do I do this?

To put this more concretely, let's say I have this class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository dao; //extends CrudRepository, annotated with @Repository

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper; 
    //Jackson library, injected from Java @Configuration annotated class

    public <...> myFunction(...){
        <...do something with the above 2 objects...>
    }
}
```

I would like to write a test for this class as follows:

```
public class MyServiceUnitTest {
    @Mock
    private MyRepository mockedRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService testedService; 
    //should inject mockedRepository and a real ObjectMapper from appconfig

    <...>
}
```

What sorts of annotations, config files, etc, do I need to make this work?  Currently I have my test class annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` but that doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried using a combination of `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` with `@SpringBootTest` which also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. But this is how I would go about it.

1. change Field injection to constructor injection in MyService class

   ```
   private MyRepository dao; 
   private ObjectMapper objectMapper; 

   @Autowired
   public MyService (MyRepository dao, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
     this.dao = dao;
     this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
   }
   ```
2. Write your test class like this

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ObjectMapper.class})
   public class MyServiceUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Mock
    private MyRepository dao; //extends CrudRepository, annotated with @Repository

    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       myService=  new MyService(dao, objectMapper);
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
      .........
    }
   }
   ```

   This way you can control what variables in your service can be mocked and what need not be mocked.
   With `@ContextConfiguration`, you can specify to the framework which needs to be loaded. So that when you Autowire it in the Test it doesn't fail. And also with it you can specify only required classes for your test and not everything.

You can achieve this with Field Injection and `@InjectMocks` as well. But with constructor injection it is better.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your runner class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Will get you the expected behavior.

Remember to call

```
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

As part of your setup process.